# Rspec tests fail after converting from SQLite 3 to Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, sqlite

I'm developing my first Rails app and using rspec & capybara for testing. When I began creating the app I was using SQLite for development/testing and pg for production.  Ran into some issues with Heroku, and successfully converted my SQLite3 database to Postgres.  Everything appears to work great except some rspec tests that were passing are now failing.

Specifically, the rspec tests now fail when I have test data in the local database.  Prior to the conversion to postgres, all of my tests were passing with test data.  During my research into this problem, I found one other stackoverflow post that reported a similar issue, but didn't find a solution.  Here's what I've done:

1. I ran "bundle exec rake db:reset" to make sure my data model from the development database was reflected in the test database.
2. Restarted the local server.  All the rspec tests passed just like they did before the database conversion. However, when I add test data, my controller tests and some model tests fail. Here the output from one respec test after I added a "member" to a model:

   `    14) Creating members displays an error when the member has no first name
     Failure/Error: expect(Member.count).to eq(0)

   expected: 0
           got: 1

   (compared using ==)`

The contents of my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'


group :doc do
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development do
gem 'spring'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
end

group :development, :test do
gem 'pg'
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :test do
gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4.3'
gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.7.0'
gem 'faker'
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.6'
gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.3.0'
gem 'launchy', '~> 2.4.2'
gem 'rspec-activemodel-mocks'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.43.0'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

My database yml file:

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
pool: 5
username: xxxxx 
password: 

development:
<<: *default
database: postgresql

test:
<<: *default
database: postgresql


production:
<<: *default
database: postgresql
```

I need help troubleshooting.  I'm guessing something went wrong with my test database when I converted from SQLite 3 to postgres.  Any ideas or suggestions to fix the problem? If I weren't attempting test driven development while learning Rails I wouldn't know there's a problem somewhere.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You should write this up as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem: I needed to put the name of my app as the "database" in the test section of my database yml file. All test are passing again. The solution seems simple now, but it wasn't obvious-- at least not to me at this stage in my learning Rails. I'll leave the post, perhaps it will help someone else.